# Create groups chat react-native using firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm beginner in react-native and I'm actually developing a real-time chat application in React-Native.I wanted to know if it is possible to create different channels (like discord) using Firebase ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can. The one keep in mind is structuring your firebase database structure.

[Structuring your Firebase Data correctly for a Complex App](https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data)

[Structure Your Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data)

For chatting app, you can reference from [chat-sdk-ios](https://github.com/chat-sdk/chat-sdk-ios/wiki/Understanding-the-Chat-SDK-data-schema)